# Visual Studio dotted folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, directory

In the Visual Studio (2010) Solution Explorer, what do the dotted "ghost" folders mean? I can still open them up and open contents within them, so how do they differ from the rest of the normal yellow folders? My reason for asking is that currently my project is missing a file that it expects to be in one of the dotted folders, so I was hoping that some insight into exactly what they mean would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: TFS will create a build based upon what is checked in I think, not what is on your local computer. So, the bin files I think are not relevant to TFS.

Comment: This question and all provided Information here still holds true for Visual Studio 2015!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means it is showing you a file or folder that typically would be hidden by Visual Studio. For example, the bin folder isn't something you typically interface with directly - when you build in VS, it adds the files into the bin folder. So, you don't really need to have access to it as it doesn't contain any editable files. However, it does still exist within the directory.

Comment: @Kyle You can also show/hide these "hideable" folders (such as the "bin" and "obj" folders) by selecting the folder's parent project in the Solution Explorer, then clicking the icon in the Solution Explorer toolbar that says "Show All Files" when you hover your mouse pointer over it

Answer (score 37):

Also this can refer to a file/folder that is not included in the project. This can be included by right clicking and selecting 'Include In Project'.

Comment: if this option is faded, what should I do to include the files/folder into project?

Comment: THANKS!  NOTE:  If you are running your app, the "Include in project" option disappears, so stop the app first.